# Merge 5.1 sound channels into 2-channel output

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

A recently installed sound card has a variety of options for me to choose from in Settings > Audio, among them "Analog Surround 5.1 Output" and "Analog Stereo Output". The former's audio is louder and of notably higher quality, but immersive surround sound (i.e. movies, video games) leaves out important parts of audio - the rear left and right, front center, and subwoofer channels don't make it through.

I've been managing by using the stereo output setting, but would like to use the higher-quality audio. Is there a way to merge the other outputs into the existing channels? Perhaps with Pulse or Alsa? Failing this, is there a way to install a virtual surround sound suite on ubuntu that makes use of the 5.1 channels?

(In specific, I would like to merge Front Left and Rear Left both into Front Left, mimic this on the right, and split Subwoofer and Front Center between Front Left and Front Right.)